# How to "ask" SharePoint what resources can be accessed?

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to "ask" SharePoint, what sites/folders a user has access to?

In other words, how to do an API call which returns a list of resources that a registered user is allowed to access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop [sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.doesuserhavepermissions.aspx) -> [webs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.doesuserhavepermissions.aspx) -> [lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.doesuserhavepermissions.aspx) -> [listitems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.doesuserhavepermissions.aspx) and use DoesUserHavePermissions on object to see if user can view/create/delete stuff.